# Checking NULL Pointer In C Doesn't Work

Tags: c, pointers, runtime-error

I have a function which returns a multiple indirection pointer as result like so:

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    char *name;
} user;

user **myfn(int users_count) {
    user **a;
    a = malloc(sizeof(user) * user_counts);
    for(int i = 0 ; i<user_counts ; i++) {
        *(a+i) = malloc(sizeof(user));
        (*(a+i))->id = 1;
        (*(a+i))->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 25);
        strncpy((*(a+i))->name, "Morteza", 25); // just for example
    }
    return a;
 }
```

Now, I when I want to crawl in this result in main function, it will show all users name, but at the end it will encounter with `Segmentation fault` error.

```
int main() {
    user **a = myfn(10);
    int i = 0;
    while((*(a+i)) != NULL) {
        printf("ID: %d \t %s\n", (*(a+i))->id, (*(a+i))->name);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
ID: 1 Morteza
ID: 2 Morteza
...
...
ID: 10 Morteza
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why `condition` of `while` doesn't work fine?

Comment: `a = malloc(sizeof(user) * user_counts);` is wrong. `*a` is a `user *`, not a `user`.

Comment: Don't use `strncpy`. Ever.

Comment: `*(a+i)` is usually written `a[i]`.

Comment: Multiplying by `sizeof (char)` is redundant. `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: Your loop condition in `main` is wrong. There is no `NULL` in your `a` array, so the loop never stops and you run off the end of the array.

Comment: @melpomene when I never tell `a = malloc(sizeof(user) * user_counts);` from where C could understand what size of pointer that I'm looking for?

Comment: What is a "2 dimension  pointer"? Pointers are scalars, i.e. they have no dimensions. And something like `int **` is not a 2D array either and cannot point to one. You seem to have major missconcentions about pointer and arrays. I'd recommend to get a good (resp. better) C book and read the corresponding chapters.

Comment: @Mortezaipo I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Olaf I know what do you mean, It was my wrong on describing. So I've updated my question.

Comment: @Mortezaipo The difference between ``char * x = 0; char *y = x + 1; assert(y == 1);`` and ``uint32_t * x = 0; uint32_t * y = x + 1; assert( (char*)y == 4);`` is the type used for the pointer arithmetic. ``malloc()`` has no say in that. Nor is there mystic meta info involved.

Comment: @melpomene you said that `a = malloc(sizeof(user) * user_counts);` is wrong. but how can I define a `user` pointer with `user_counts` size?

Comment: @Mortezaipo The correct version would be `a = malloc(sizeof (user *) * user_counts);` (dynamically allocate `user_counts` pointers) but I'd actually write that as `a = malloc(user_counts * sizeof *a);` so I don't have to worry about the correct type.

Comment: fix like [this](http://ideone.com/8kASSW)

Comment: @melpomene Thank you so much.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you so much! It works fine! I have a question, is it a correct way? or it's not common?

Comment: It is a common ordinary way.

Comment: @Mortezaipo The general rule is when the pointer has N stars in the declaration, you use N-1 stars in the `sizeof` argument in `malloc()`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thank you so much!

Comment: @Barmar thanks a lot!

Comment: Can I ask why are you using a double indirection? It doesn't seem to be needed in the example you posted.

Comment: @Bob__ well I have a list of random data which is like a table. `ID, Title, Is_Done, Created` . so I've thought that I need double indirection pointer.

Comment: If you write `a = malloc( sizeof *a * user_counts)`, you don't have to think about the type of *a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all,

```
a = malloc(sizeof(user) * user_counts);
```

has a problem - you want to allocate `user_counts` instances of *pointers* to `user`, not instances of `user`, so that line should be

```
a = malloc(sizeof(user *) * user_counts);
```

However, there's an easier way around this - the `sizeof` operator can take *expressions* as arguments as well as type names.  So you can rewrite that line as

```
a = malloc( sizeof *a * user_counts );
```

The *expression* `*a` has type `user *`, so `sizeof *a` is equivalent to `sizeof (user *)`.  This makes your life a bit simpler, in that you don't have to puzzle out the type that `a` points to - make the compiler do the hard work.

You should *always* check the result of a `malloc` call.

```
a = malloc( sizeof *a * users_count );
if ( a )
{
  // do stuff with a
}
```

Second of all, don't use `*(a+i)` to index into `a` - use `a[i]` instead.  Makes things a bit easier to read.  So,

```
   *(a+i) = malloc(sizeof(user));
    (*(a+i))->id = 1;
    (*(a+i))->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 25);
```

becomes

```
   a[i] = malloc(sizeof *a[i]);
   if ( a[i] )
   {
     a[i]->id = 1;
     a[i]->name = malloc(sizeof *a[i]->name * 25);
   }
   else
   {
     /* deal with memory allocation failure */
   }
```

Now, to your actual problem.  Your code is crashing for one of the following reasons:

- the initial `malloc` of `a` failed, so you're crashing on the first line that uses `a[i]`;
- the `malloc` of one of your `a[i]` failed, so you're crashing on `a[i]->id = 1`;
- you've successfully allocated memory for all `users_count` elements of `a` - *no* `a[i]` is `NULL`, so you loop past the last element of your array and try to dereference the object immediately following it, which is *most likely* not a valid pointer.

In addition to adding the checks after each `malloc` call, you should probably loop based on `users_count`:

```
for ( i = 0; i < users_count; i++ )
  printf("ID: %d \t %s\n", a[i]->id, a[i]->name);
```

Or, you need to allocate one extra element for `a` and set it to `NULL`:

```
a = malloc( sizeof *a * (users_count + 1) );
if ( a )
{
  a[users_count] = NULL;
  for ( i = 0; i < users_count; i++ )
    ...
}
```

Note that `calloc` initializes all allocated memory to 0, so you can use that and not worry about explicitly setting an element to `NULL`:

```
a = calloc( users_count + 1, sizeof *a );
if ( a )
{
  for ( i = 0; i < users_count; i++ )
    ...
}
```

Comment: Technically setting a pointer to all-bits-zero (as `calloc` does) is not guaranteed to produce a null pointer.

Comment: @melpomene Do you have a reference for that?  C Standard, *6.3.2.3 Pointers*, paragraph 3, states "An  integer  constant  expression  with  the  value  0,  or  such  an  expression  cast  to  type
`void *`, is called a *null pointer constant*. ..."  That would at least be an implementation-dependent `NULL` pointer value on most platforms, I'd think.
.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't see how this applies here. `calloc(...)` doesn't involve any integer constant expression with the value 0.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Adding extra element and assigning that to `NULL` value, is it the standard way?

Comment: @Mortezaipo: Normally, no - you'd use a separate object to keep track of the number of elements in the array, which you're already doing with `users_count`.  String processing is about the only place where you'd rely on a 0-valued sentinel to mark the end of an array's contents.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Specifically, 5.18: "Q: Is a run-time integral value of 0, cast to a pointer, guaranteed to be a null pointer? A: No. Only constant integral expressions with value 0 are guaranteed to indicate null pointers. See also questions 4.14, 5.2, and 5.19."  This is something I forget from time to time and have to be reminded of.  Remember, 6.3.2.3/3 says "an **integer constant expression** with the value 0...".  A runtime 0 is not an *integer constant expression*.

Comment: @JohnBode well sometimes I should use database results which is not defined how many records it has. So what about this situation? I mean when I don't want to define `users_count` in my main function like `myfn(0)` which it means `all records`, what should I do then?

Comment: @Mortezaipo: Depends on the database API, then - if it doesn't return the number of records returned, or if it doesn't provide a cursor for you to iterate through the result set, then it should add a sentinel record at the end of the sequence.  If I understand what you're saying, anyway.

Comment: @JohnBode Thank you so much!